# 2x AMD Opteron 6128 VS 2x Xeon E5620

Tags: xeon, central-processing-unit, windows-server-core

Which one of these processors would win on windows server 2008 IIS and MSSQL server. There is 24 GB ram.

Comment: It would depend heavily on your load. Not all IIS & SQL servers are the same. Those processors are quite different, and there is no easy comparison.

Comment: i need performance at peak load. and server is really heavlly loaded. i belive i can see 100% cpu usage easly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with the Opteron. Having 8 physical cores will deliver much more bang than 4 physical + 4 virtual (through Hyperthreading), although the Xeon compensates slightly by having a higher clock rate.

Overall it depends on your load. If you are running low load 80%+ of your time, you might consider power consumption to be a priority instead. The Xeon platform will likely give you less overall power consumption.

Comment: If the load is entirely serial, those extra cores aren't going to mean anything at all. If it's highly parallel, it will depend on the type of processing being doing. There's just no quick way to answer this one and trying to distill it down to 'these cores are better than those cores' isn't helping.

Comment: Well i need peak server load performance. And only MSSQL and IIS server will be used nothing else. I dont know how good MSSQL and IIS at parallellization.  Also power consumption is not important.